# How to create circular progress timers on a bootstrap carousel indicator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I have a bootstrap 3 carousel with 4 slides and can't figure out how to make the carousel-indicator dots a circular progress bar. I would like for each dot to have a circular loading animation.

Comment: Do you have an example to provide to us ?